# phpmyadmin - can't log in without a password

Tags: phpmyadmin

I set AllowNoPassword to true and I still have that I can't login without password

Answer (score 1):

Did you uncomment this line in the config by removing the `//`?

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE
```